# What should be line terminator here

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a short script to read each file in folder of script files and print last word its first line - indicating executable file that is run- `ocaml` e.g. in `usr/bin/ocaml`

```
#use "topfind" 
#require "str"

(* fn to print binary file being called from hashbang line of script file *)
let rec myfn (afile) = 
    print_string (afile^": ");
    if (Sys.is_directory afile) then print_endline("This is a directory.");
    let ic = (open_in afile) in
    if in_channel_length(ic)==0 then print_endline("Zero length file."); exit 0
    let line = input_line(ic) in    (* error here *)
    if (Str.first_chars line 0 = "#") then
        let linelist = (Str.split (Str.regexp "/") line) in    
        let lastword = List.nth linelist ((List.length linelist) - 1) in 
        print_endline(lastword)
    else
        print_endline("Not a script file.") ;; 

(* to check all files in directory *)
let dir = "." in 
let files = Sys.readdir dir in 
Array.iter myfn files;;
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
File "firstline3.ml", line 13, characters 27-29:
Error: Syntax error
```

I have tried to replace `in` with `;` or no terminator in this line but it does not help. What is the problem and how can it be solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My guess would be a missing line terminator after `exit 0` in the previous line

Comment: If I put `exit 0;;` I get `Error: Unbound value ic` in line above. If I replace `in` there with `;;`, I get `syntax error` in that line.

Comment: How about a single semicolon instead?

Comment: There is a warning `Warning 21: this statement never returns (or has an unsound type.)` but function then runs one file only and does not loop for all files. Actually, I want loop to continue here but there is no `continue` keyword in Ocaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing parentheses around the `then` expression:

```
if in_channel_length ic =0 then ( print_endline "Zero length file."; exit 0 );
```

otherwise the expression is read by the parser as

```
(if in_channel_length ic = 0 then print_endline "Zero length file.");
exit 0;
```

and the exit is thus unconditional.

Note, you should avoid the physical equality operator, `==`, (especially on non-mutable values) and use `=` instead.

EDIT: If you want to return, you just need to add an else branch

```
if in_channel_length ic = 0 then print_endline "Zero length file."
else ....
```

Comment: Actually, I want it to exit fn, so return rather than exit program. But `Ocaml` does not have `return`.

Comment: Indeed, there are other errors. You should check what `Str.first_chars line 0` returns.

Comment: It is always returning false. If I replace `"#"` with `'#'`, then there is a type mismatch error - char vs string.

Comment: You should really try to print `Str.first_chars "a word" 0`.

Comment: Try that in a separate toplevel instance.